# How to apply DRY rule?

Tags: python

Is there a way to simplify the following into two lines of code, instead of four?

```
# convert to minutes (int)
if isinstance(r1, datetime.time):
    r1 = r1.minute + (r1.hour * 60)
if isinstance(r2, datetime.time):
    r2 = r2.minute + (r2.hour * 60)
```

Comment: @PadraicCunningham why not? At what point would you consider it repeating? For example, what if there were 5 r's instead of 2

Answer (score 2):

Sure:

```
def accumulateMinutesIfDateTime(r):
    if not isinstance(r, datetime.time):
        return r

    return r.minute + r.hour * 60

# ...

r1 = accumulateMinutesIfDateTime(r1)
r2 = accumulateMinutesIfDateTime(r2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it shorter, but probably less understandable:

```
r1, r2 = [r.minute + (r.hour * 60) if isinstance(r, datetime.time) else r for r in (r1, r2)]
```

Comment: If you are going to try to do it in one line use a generator expression `r1, r2 = (r.minute + (r.hour * 60) if isinstance(r, datetime.time) else r for r in (r1, r2))`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham What's the purpose of using a generator to enumerate *two* elements?

Answer (score 0):

```
func = lambda r: r.minute + (r.hour * 60) if isinstance(r, datetime.time) else r
r1, r2 = func(r1), func(r2)
```